# EF Core 7 Json Column mapping for array

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a sql table with a json column 'Extras'

```
  [{"Key":"Part Number","Value":123},{"Key":"Batch Number","Value":321},{"Key":"Quantity","Value":"3"}]
```

I'm trying to map it to my class LinerReceiptLog. I added a new class called tag that has Key and Value properties

```
public partial class LinerReceiptLog
{
    public long LinerReceiptLogId { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }

    public int TotalQty { get; set; }

    public string Ncrnumber { get; set; }

    public List<Tag> Extras { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I updated the model builder

```
entity.OwnsMany(e => e.Extras, builder=>builder.ToJson());
```

When I run the code to query the db context
I get this exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The requested operation requires an element of type 'Array', but the target element has type 'Object'.'
```

I've been following this article
https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2023/02/14/getting-started-entity-framework-core-7-json-support/